# Flexible subseting data.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm working with census data. The Data-set looks like below: It's a collection of Households (or families) which is identified with an `Id` and every member of a household has an `Id.in.HH`. Each household has a head. Every entity in household has a `relation` to household head [`1` means head, `2` means head's spouse, `3` means head's child]. For example the family with `Id == 1` has 4 memebers with `Id.in.HH` ranging from 1 to 4. This Household has a head [`Id == 1 & Id.in.HH == 3`] which is clear from it's `Relation.to.Head` value [`Relation.to.Head == 1`]. and so on. `Gender` has two values [`1: male`, `2: female`]. Data-set comes from a country that polygamy is allowed for males. I want to add a column in which family `Type` is calculated. If it's a family with a male Head and one wife [`Type := 1`], If it's a family with a female head and one husband [`Type:= 2`], and if it's a family with a male head with several wives [`Type:= 3`]. For every kid, her/his mother's `Id.In.HH` is noted. I want to add a column consisting her/his mother's birth date. I'm working with `data.table` but an amateur.

```
Id  Id.in.HH  Relation.to.Head  Gender  Mother.Id.In.HH Birth
1   1         2                 1       NA              1950
1   2         3                 2       3               1975
1   4         3                 2       3               1980
1   3         1                 2       NA              1955
2   2         1                 1       NA              1943             
2   3         2                 2       NA              1945        
2   1         2                 2       NA              1960     
2   5         3                 1       3               1964
2   4         3                 2       1               1980        
3   2         1                 1       NA              1975      
3   3         2                 2       NA              1977    
3   1         3                 1       3               1994
```

What I want it to look like is:

```
Id  Id.in.HH  Relation.to.Head  Gender  Mother.Id.In.HH Birth  Type  Mom.Birth
1   1         2                 1       NA              1950   2     NA
1   2         3                 2       3               1975   2     1955
1   4         3                 2       3               1980   2     1955
1   3         1                 2       NA              1955   2     NA
2   2         1                 1       NA              1943   3     NA           
2   3         2                 2       NA              1945   3     NA 
2   1         2                 2       NA              1960   3     NA
2   5         3                 1       3               1964   3     1945
2   4         3                 2       1               1980   3     1960    
3   2         1                 1       NA              1975   1     NA         
3   3         2                 2       NA              1977   1     NA
3   1         3                 1       3               1994   1     1977
```

I have tried @jlhoward solution in this way:

```
familyType <- function(relation, gender) {
  polygamy = sum(relation == 2, na.rm = TRUE)
  headgender = gender[relation == 1]
  polygamy = as.integer(levels(polygamy))[polygamy]
  headgender = as.integer(levels(headgender))[headgender]
  if(polygamy == 0) {
    if(headgender == 1){
      return (1L)
    } else {
      return (2L)
    }
  } else if(polygamy == 1){
    if(headgender == 1){
      return (3L)
    } else {
      return (4L)
    }
  } else if(polygamy > 1) {
    return (5L)
  }
}

tbl[, type:=familyType(Relation.to.Head, Gender), by=Id]
```

But I got this error:

```
Error in if (polygamy == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your desired result. The first 4 rows are a family. Rows 2 and 3 are children. The children were born in 1975 and 1980. Their mother was born in 1980?? How can this be?

Comment: @jlhoward I corrected it. The Mom.Birth column usese Mother.Id.In.HH to find the row's mother (with Id.in.HH). Then replicates the corresponding Birth in the new column.

Comment: To start here's the logic for Male Head One Wife `any(df$Relation.to.Head == 1 & df$Gender == 1) && sum(df$Relation.to.Head == 2) == 1
`. Relation.to.Head is 1 and Gender is 1 is a male head. sum(Relation.to.Head == 2) is the amount of spouses. We set that equal to 1 for only one wife. It returns `TRUE` correctly for rows 10 - 13 (household 3)

Comment: I don't think that this kind of stuff works: `dt[Relation.to.Head == 1 & Gender == 1 && sum(Relation.to.Head == 2) == 1, Type := 1, by=Id]`! @PierreLafortune

Comment: That was simply an introduction to the logic. My `data.table` package is corrupted after trying the new 1.96 download so I can't work in it now.

Comment: @jlhoward There's something with my implementation of your solution. I modified the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really two questions. Here's the first part.

```
get.type <- function(relation,gender) {
  if (sum(relation==2)>1) return(3L)
  gender[relation==1]
}
DT[,Type:=get.type(Relation.to.Head,Gender), by=Id]
```

Using @PierreLafortune's excellent approach to the second part:

```
DT[, Mom.Birth := Birth[match(Mother.Id.In.HH, Id.in.HH)], by=Id]
DT
#     Id Id.in.HH Relation.to.Head Gender Mother.Id.In.HH Birth Type Mom.Birth
#  1:  1        1                2      1              NA  1950    2        NA
#  2:  1        2                3      2               3  1975    2      1955
#  3:  1        4                3      2               3  1980    2      1955
#  4:  1        3                1      2              NA  1955    2        NA
#  5:  2        2                1      1              NA  1943    3        NA
#  6:  2        3                2      2              NA  1945    3        NA
#  7:  2        1                2      2              NA  1960    3        NA
#  8:  2        5                3      1               3  1964    3      1945
#  9:  2        4                3      2               1  1980    3      1960
# 10:  3        2                1      1              NA  1975    1        NA
# 11:  3        3                2      2              NA  1977    1        NA
# 12:  3        1                3      1               3  1994    1      1977
```

Comment: How does the `if` work? Specifically although I've seen it several times but O don't know what does `3L` mean.

Comment: Type `?"if"` at the commend line for docs on the `if` statement. `3L` means treat the number 3 as an integer (rather than double).

Comment: That's nice +1. Amin, the statement reads "If the sum of spouses in the household is greater than 1 output the integer 3 and stop. If not, output the gender of the head of the household."

Comment: [Temporarily] Thanks guys. According to the laws of stackoverflow I should edit this post in a way that consist only one question and post another one with the second question?

Comment: It's all good. Here's an answer to the second part. `dt[, Mom.Birth := Birth[match(Mother.Id.In.HH, Id.in.HH)], by=Id]`

Comment: @PierreLafortune You should post that as an answer. It's much better than what I came up with.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(dplyr)

family.head_gender =
  person %>%
  filter(Relation.to.Head == 1) %>%
  select(Id, head_gender = Gender)

family.type = 
  person %>%
  filter(Relation.to.Head == 2) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarize(number_of_spouses = n() ) %>%
  left_join(family.head_gender) %>%
  mutate(type = 
           ifelse(head_gender == 1,
             ifelse(number_of_spouses = 1,
               1,
               3),
             2)) %>%
  select(-head_gender, -number_of_spouses)

person.final = 
  person %>%
  left_join(
    person %>%
    select(Mother.Id.In.HH = Id.In.HH,
           Mom.Birth = Birth) ) %>%
  left_join(family.type)
```

Comment: My data-set consists about 1.4 M rows. `dplyr`'s `group_by` takes so much time in comparison to `data.table` corresponding functions. @bramtayl